# Getting error when configure push settings - FWLSE3000E

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

FWLSE3000E: A server error was detected.
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 8 path $

[FWLSE3000E](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egMr6.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug that causes this. A permanent fix is currently being worked on.

The workaround the problem, navigate to the Settings > Server Configuration tab and click on the "copy from sample" button. Then save your changes.

This is required only until the fix is put in place.

Comment: the same problem appears again after deleteing all apps and services and recreate a new mobile foundation App

Comment: -- I try your step  
Settings > Server Configuration tab and click on the "copy from sample" button.
but the same error still appears

Comment: Hi Adar, We are getting the same error in MFP version 8.0.0.00-20171123-0641. Created a PMR, But not received any proper solution. PMR# 79770-L6Q-000.

Answer (score 0):

New fixes are delivered recently. Can you try again hitting recreate button again.

Answer (score 0):

this usually means that in the server.xml there is some mismatch in JNDI properties . espeicaly `mfpadmin/mfp.push.authorization.client.id` and `imfpush/mfp.push.authorization.client.id` as well as their secret. also make sure the hostnames inside `imfpush/mfp.push.authorization.server.url` and the rest of the admin URL JNDI properties

(like `<jndiEntry jndiName="mfpconsole/mfp.admin.endpoint" value='"http://myhost:9080/mfpadmin"'/>` )

are pointing to same hostname and that host  is pingable. then after you checked those : a server restart is required to fix the problem.